# Knowing the range of the visible X axis on dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm using dygraphs to print two curves on a single graph, and the user have to be able to resize it, at least in the X axis.

I succeed doing this, but now, I'd want to calculate some values (like the average value) in function of the visible curve. (I want a local average changing when the user move/zoom the graph).

How do I get the range of the X axis when the user zoomed/move the graph ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just looked at [the dygraphs documentation](http://dygraphs.com) in more details.

There is a function to do this 
([see here](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#xAxisRange))
 : `xAxisRange()`.

It returns an array of two `Date`.